Publish Exchange calendar publicly with multiple configurations
I have my calendar published in Exchange 2010 such that I have links I can use to anonymously get the details of the calendar as an ICS, with all details available, which I use for accessing my calendar from my own private applications and systems.
What I'd like to do is also have a separate pair of links that I can disseminate more broadly, which only contain free/busy information. While this is one of the options, I can't seem to generate additional links since the calendar is already shared with details, i.e. it seems I can only share the calendar in one configuration, not multiple:


Is there something I'm missing here that would allow it to be shared multiple different ways? In the online outlook.com / Office365, it's possible to do that, but I haven't found any documentation that says it can't be done in the on-premises versions (shown below, I already have an "all details" link published, and I have the option of sharing it again, with free/busy):

Is it possible to share a calendar in each possible configuration with Exchange 2010 like it is with outlook.com / Exchange Online, or is only one configuration at a time possible?
I'm aware of iCal proxy tools like https://github.com/scy/calproxy which could possibly provide a filtered free/busy view, but it seems like a lot of bother to set something like that up if there is a way to accomplish this natively.

In Exchange 2010, the ability to publish a calendar with multiple different visibility options (like "all details" and "free/busy") is not as flexible as it is in Exchange Online or outlook.com. Exchange 2010 generally allows you to publish a calendar with a single configuration at a time.
Here are a few possible workarounds:

You can create a separate calendar that only contains free/busy information. This way, you can share one calendar with detailed information and another with just free/busy information. The second calendar would need to be manually updated or synchronized with your main calendar, which is not ideal but might be a feasible workaround.
As you've mentioned, tools like calproxy could be used to filter the ICS feed to only show free/busy information. While this involves additional setup, it can automate the process and ensure that you don’t have to manually manage multiple calendars.
If you are within an organization and want to share your calendar with specific people, you can set their access permissions to only show free/busy information while keeping detailed access for others. This can be done using the Calendar Permissions tab in Outlook or through PowerShell scripts. However, this won't help with anonymous access through ICS links.

Unfortunately, due to the limitations of Exchange 2010, there isn't a native way to have multiple anonymous ICS links with different visibility settings directly from the calendar sharing options. If moving to Exchange Online or Office 365 is an option, it might be worth considering for its more flexible sharing capabilities.
